# Encode non-lower ASCII characters

Tags: php, encoding

I'm trying to encode strings like `Hügelkultur` in PHP to `H&#xFC;gelkultur`.

I'm trying things like `htmlentities(str)` and `htmlentities(str, ENT_XML1)` but it leaves it unchanged. `urlencode(str)` gave me `H%C3%BCgelkultur` but that isn't what I'm trying to get.

What function should I use? Does that type of encoding have a name?

Comment: Is there a file involved, or other source? Taking a look at some of your other questions,  seen one being db-related; is this related to that also?

Comment: Because if you specify your encoding properly you don't have to do this at all. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner it is related. I was able to get it out of the SQLite database in one format but not in the exact way I need it to be. I was hoping to use PHP which is more versatile to modify the file from the database to get where it needs to be.

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in for this because you only have this problem if you're doing other, more important things incorrectly and this just papers over them.

See: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

But if you're committed to not actually fixing that and making your application more difficult to maintain, you could use the following to encode UTF-8 codepoints above 127 as HTML entities:

```
function force_utf8_entities($input) {
    return implode('', array_map(
        function($a){
            if( strlen($a) > 1 ) {
                return sprintf("&#x%X;", mb_ord($a));
            }
            return $a;
        },
        mb_str_split($input)
    ));
}

$input = "Hügelkultur";
var_dump(
    force_utf8_entities($input)
);
```

It's also worth noting that there's no such thing as "non-lower ASCII", as every byte with an ordinal representation above 127 is entirely at the mercy of the declared encoding. UTF, ISO8859-X, and MS cpXXXX encodings will all hotly disagree about what those bytes represent on the screen.

This is where the term "7-bit safe" comes from, because no matter how badly you muck up your encodings in transit, you can be reasonably sure that bytes below 127 will make it through.

### edit

"Extended ASCII" still is not a thing.

If you display a byte above 127 the symbol presented on the screen will be different depending on the encoding it is interpreted as. People with western-european alphabets are somewhat coddled because our funny accented letters tend to be the defaults [ISO8859-1 and cp1252] but when you switch to eastern-european charsets [ISO8859-5 and cp1251] you're going to see `ќ` instead of `ü`.

It's worth noting that the `FC` in `&#xFC;` is not a byte value, it is the un-encoded UTF code point. Again, users of western-european alphabets are spoiled, and frequently confused, by the overlap in the code point space. `uFC` encoded as UTF-8 is the literal two-byte sequence `C3 BC`. hence your `urlencode()` output.

Really, the truth is that there's not such thing as "ASCII" at all. It's just that most non-asian encodings tend to agree that it's easier to just leave the traditional first 127 bytes the same everywhere so as not to freak out the english people.

Comment: Just thought I'd say that I liked what you submitted.

Comment: Senpai has noticed me. (๑•́ω•̀๑)

Comment: Thank you! I was searching for the term extended ASCII but it wasn't coming to mind. I'm trying to wrap my head around the code. I'm not able to use mb_str_split() (undefined function). I see its multibyte. That's going to be pretty much required for what I need, isn't it? The formatting mismatch is being driven by data from two different sources (openzim and sqlite) that need to be matched up for a different destination (graphviz). If it was my code I could fix the problems there, but I'm limited to the output I can get.

Comment: `mb_str_split()` is available only since PHP 7.4